# how I can change whitespaces between words of a string in print order?

Tags: python, string, printf

i was writing a code to input a sentence of user then change its whitespaces to ... and print the sentence.

hi rocks
I intended to input a sentence and change its whitespaces to "..."
I wrote this code:

```
    a=input("inter your sentence: ")
    #split in to n str
    #print every str with ... as whitespace
    a=a.split()
    for x in a:
        print(x, sep='...',end="")
```

if I input **this is a test**, i expected to see

this...is...a...test

but it doesn't work
it gives me

"thisisatest

Comment: Maybe write `a.replace(" ", "...")`

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) or do any research into how the `sep` argument works? What does specifying `sep` do when you're only printing _one_ object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this.

```
a=input("inter your sentence: ")
#split in to n str
#print every str with ... as whitespace
a=a.split()
print(*a, sep='...')
```

Or do this.

```
a=input("inter your sentence: ")
#split in to n str
#print every str with ... as whitespace
a=a.split()
final_a = '...'.join(a)
print(final_a)
```

OUTPUT (for input `this is a test`)

```
this...is...a...test
```

---

Replying OP's comment. *`"so what you think about this one for x in range(0,10): print (x ,sep='...', end="") it didn't work too"`*

```
for x in range(0,10):
    print(x ,sep='...', end="")
```

Note: `sep` seprate `args` provide in print method, Default `sep=" "`
Example:

```
print("one","1", sep="-->")
# Output: one-->1
```

And `end`: When every args print in terminal then print see the `end` value and print it in terminal. Default `end="\n"` `\n → newline`

Example:

```
for a in range(0, 10):
    print(a, end=".|.")

#Output= 0.|.1.|.2.|.3.|.4.|.5.|.6.|.7.|.8.|.9.|. 

# Here when 0 prints then print method also print `end`'s value after that, and 1 then `end`'s value and so on.
```

Answer for your comment's question can be this.

```
for x in range(0,10):
    print(x,end='...')
```

Output

As I say `end`'s value print after every print method args print, so `'...'` also prints after `x` last value(`9`).

```
0...1...2...3...4...5...6...7...8...9...
```

Comment: so what you think about this one    for x in range(0,10):
    print (x ,sep='...', end="") it didn't work too

Comment: @ZahraRamezani I have answered this in the post you can see the updated code.

Comment: tnx dear :))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

[`str.replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) can be used to replace one or multiple characters of same ASCII value to another. In your case, it would be:

```py
a=input("inter your sentence: ")
a=a.replace(' ', '...')
print(a)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I know about replace method but I specially want to use print parameter.

Comment: in addition if user input 2 space we have 2 "...".isn't it?   e.g  I input 'this is    a test' so I will have this...is.........a...test     I put 3 space between is and a

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Python join and split functions in this case:

**The code snippet:**

```
inputSentence = input("Enter your sentence: ")

print("...".join(inputSentence.split()))
```

**The output:**

```
Enter your sentence: This is a test

This...is...a...test
```

Comment: Instead of attaching a screenshot, copy and paste the output of the program.